# Can I move photos from Dropbox to Google Photos without downloading?

Tags: dropbox, google-photos

I have photos stored in Dropbox.  I want to move them to Google Photos.  I don't have enough free space on my hard drive to download them all and then upload them all.  Is there any way to move them directly from Dropbox to Google Photos?

Comment: Do you already have the photos in your local Dropbox folder?

Comment: No, I only have them in Dropbox's cloud storage, I don't have them locally.

Comment: Look for a solution that will let you sync data between Dropbox and Google Drive. I'm sure there's a question here asking about that sort of thing but I can't search for it right now. Once in Google Drive it's academic to "suck" the photos into Google Photos.

Answer (score 3):

I solved it in no time with https://app.mover.io/ (freemium. I used it once to do a massive, one-time moving)

Just authorize both apps to be connected through the web interface and you're all set! You can see a progress report and in a few hours (I was moving 7-8GB) you'll have your files transferred.

Comment: How did you do this using Mover? I can only see local files in my dropbox account, and I don't see Google Photos as an alternative to move to..